# What would be better long term: Creating many documents in MongoDB or fewer documents with nested arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have a scenario I'm debating for my app.

Let's say I have a Quiz application with a MongoDB structure that looks like this:

```
{
  _id: xxxxxx,
  userId: xxxx,
  quizData: [
   {
    name: xxxx,
    quizId: xxxx, 
    questions: [...]
   },
   {
    name: xxxx,
    quizId: xxxx, 
    questions: [...]
   }
[...]
}
```

I'm torn between what's better long-term for my application: let each user have just one document and for each quiz he/she creates, it will be added to the "quizData" array of objects...OR...let each user's quiz have its own document in the MongoDB, where I create the above structure for each quiz (obviously, the "quizData" will only contain one object instead of an array of many).

Theoretically, the user can create as many Quizzes as they want, but realistically, that probably won't be the case. I fear that if I let each user have it's own document for each quiz in the MongoDB, it will populate the collection fast and over time (with many users doing the same), it will slow down the querying process.

Anyone have any thoughts on the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Your question can be rephrased to [one-to-many relationship with embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) VS [one-to-many relationship with document references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

There is no better or worst, it all depends on your use case. In your case for the long run, I think it's better off to go with one-to-many relationship with document references for these reasons I can think of:

1. There is a 16mb limit of document size, if the user creates a ton of quiz, the document for this user will exceed the 16mb limit quickly.
2. At some point down the road when the number of quiz of all users grows into billions, you might want to do some operations(ex:analytics, optimization, etc) on those quiz data but not mess with the user data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that a user wont create so many quizzes then that will probably be a one to few and you could embed the quiz data in the user data itself. It all depends on your data access patterns.

Example if your data access pattern is such that you normally show all quizzes associated with a user every time you get a user you are better off at embedding otherwise you will have to join that data in your application or make use of $lookup etc to join data and that can slow your application down. But beware about the restrictions as mentioned by s-hunter.